# Rendering Animation quicky

Tags: rendering, animation

I'm about to render a minute long animation with one lamp and one camera. Are there any ways to reduce the render speed besides changing the quality and fps?
Please put as many of possible because I'm only going to have about 96 hours.

Comment: Take a look at these: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-speed-up-cycles/ and https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/13-ways-to-reduce-render-times/ May be super helpful.

Comment: What render engine? What else can you tell us about your scene? Please edit your question and add more infom

Comment: Maybe this tutorial might help: http://www.blendernation.com/2016/03/15/quick-viewport-rendering-blender-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Options:

- get a faster computer
- use sheepit (https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/index.php)
- mess with the render settings so that you don't have to use as many samples